# Set ToggleButton to play default sound when clicked?

Tags: android, click, audio, togglebutton

My android apps has a regular button:

```xml
<Button
  android:id="@+id/allOnButton"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginRight="130dp"
  android:text="@string/sensor_management_all_on" />
```

And a toggle button:

```xml
<ToggleButton
  android:id="@+id/accelerometerToggleButton"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:checked="true"
  android:textOff="off"
  android:textOn="on" />
```

When the button is pressed, a nice "click" sound is played, which gives a good feedback to the user that the button was actually pressed.

How do I set a click sound for the ToggleButton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a click sound to be heard, you need clickListener to be set.

So set a dummy `onClickListener` onto the `ToggleButton`, it should play the sound effect.

Comment: WTF? Well it works but how did you figure that out? Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.sound);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.theme);
    if(toggleButton.isChecked())
        mp.start();
    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!toggleButton.isChecked()){
                mp.pause();
            }
            else {
                mp.start();
                mp.isLooping();
            }
        }
     });
```